Realizar join con dos tablas en LinQ
Cordial saludo.
En la actualidad estamos intentando en realizar un metodo en LinQ que nos permita hacer dos join, cada uno de estos con una tabla diferente. De esa forma, el metodo nos permitirá tener la nueva tabla con las dos columnas que deseamos construir las cuales son "Obra" y "Estado".
Esta es nuestra consulta:
        [HttpGet("/Llantas/Mantenimientos/Obras", Name = "GetLlantasMantenimientosAgregarObras")]
    public List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras> GetLlantasMantenimientosAgregarObras(int Anhos, int Mes)
    {
        try
        {
            var q = from a in context.GeneMttoPrev
                    // 2024-06-20: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
                    join b1 in context.GeneAlmacenObra on
                            a.bodega
                        equals
                            b1.Bodega
                        into GrupoB
                    // 2024-06-20: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        // 2024-06-20: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla c1)
                    join c1 in context.LlanHistoria on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    {
                        Equipo = a.equipo,
                        Fecha = a.fecha_mantenimiento
                    }
                    equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    {
                        Equipo = c1.equipo,
                        Fecha = c1.Fecha
                    }
                    into GrupoC
                    // 2024-06-20: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from c in GrupoC.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where
                        a.fecha_mantenimiento.Year == Anhos
                        &&
                        (
                            Mes == 0
                            ||
                            Mes == a.fecha_mantenimiento.Month
                        )
                    select new TemGeneMttoPrevObras
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                        ciclo = a.ciclo,
                        frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                        unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
                        fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
                        fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
                        horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
                        resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
                        emp = a.emp,
                        FechaInsert = a.FechaInsert,
                        // 2024-06-21: Se agrega el nombre de la obra de la tabla indicada.
                        Obra = b.Obra,
                        // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                        Estado = c == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
                    };
            // 2024-06-24: Se ordenan dos campos.
            return q.OrderBy(a => a.Obra).ThenBy(a => a.Estado).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return TemGeneMttoPrevObrasExcepcion;
        }
    }

Con el proposito de validar que todo funcione correctamente, oprimimos la tecla F5 para ejecutar el metodo, lo cual permite que se abra una nueva venta en Swagger. En Swagger se solicitan las variables Anho y mes. Al ingresar estos estos datos y ejecutar, notamos que el metodo no se ejecuta correctamente y se va a la opcion catch (Exception), lo que quiere decir que nuestro metodo tiene un problema.
Como no comoncemos en si cual es el problema, realizamos un debug al metodo para identificar en si cual es la cuasa del problema. Para esto, ponemos un punto de control a dicho metodo, procedemos a oprimir la tecla F5, ejecutamos el metodo linea a linea y logramos identificar el siguietne error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GeneMttoPrev>()
.LeftJoin(
    inner: DbSet<GeneAlmacenObra>(), 
    outerKeySelector: g => (object)g.bodega, 
    innerKeySelector: g0 => (object)g0.Bodega, 
    resultSelector: (g, g0) => new TransparentIdentifier<GeneMttoPrev, GeneAlmacenObra>(
        Outer = g, 
        Inner = g0
    ))
.LeftJoin(
    inner: DbSet<LlanHistoria>(), 
    outerKeySelector: ti => new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros{ 
        Equipo = ti.Outer.equipo, 
        Fecha = ti.Outer.fecha_mantenimiento 
    }
    , 
    innerKeySelector: l => new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros{ 
        Equipo = l.equipo, 
        Fecha = l.Fecha 
    }
    , 
    resultSelector: (ti, l) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<GeneMttoPrev, GeneAlmacenObra>, LlanHistoria>(
        Outer = ti, 
        Inner = l
    ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Esto es otra parte del error que se genera:
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
AnalistaFlotasWAPIL.Controllers.LlantasController.GetLlantasMantenimientosAgregarObras(int, int) in LlantasController.cs

Pensamos que el problema era hacer dos join en un mismo metodo, por lo cual solo dejamos un join, pero a pesar de ello, continuan apareciendo errores.
Nuestra idea inicial es poder hacer ambos join en el mismo metodo.
En el momento no hemo logrado corregir el error.
Agradecemos su ayuda.

A ver prueba quitar los new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros y dejar solo new

Hola Yussef, muchas gracias por el comentario. Haciendo esto ahora mes sale un error por datos null. Me podrías explicar porque no puedo usar   TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros ya que tenía entendido que al instanciar se evitan errores de tipos de datos.

Esa consulta Linq que tienes se convierte en una consulta SQL, esto no es siempre posible sobre todo cuando utilizas elementos que existen en C# pero no existen en SQL. El error que tienes es justamente ese, yo sospecho que es porque usas clases con nombre, pero no estoy seguro (yo llevo años haciendo esto y nunca había utilizado una clase con nombre en un join)

Saludos
Ese error conozco dos formas de tratarlo:
1.- Comparar con objetos anónimos
El error se genera al crear instancia de objetos TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros (que es ajeno al Entity) con que buscas hacer la comparación. Te sugiero Usar multiples campos con objetos anónimos (está en inglés)
Si por tu lógica de negocios al objeto TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros su método de comparación lo reescribiste (sobre-escribiste) es decir los dos campos allí poblados e inicializados no son lo único que se compara; te sugiero la opción 2.
2.- Convertir a Enumerable
Esto afecta el rendimiento; ya que cada fila de la respectiva tabla la transforma en un objeto "ajeno" a Entity; con esto ya tu new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros{..} equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros{..} que tienes quedarían sin cambios; seria por ejemplo (a los primeros; pero debe ser a todos):
var q = from a in context.GeneMttoPrev.AsEnumerable()
       // 2024-06-20: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
        join b1 in context.GeneAlmacenObra.AsEnumerable() on
            a.bodega
        equals
            b1.Bodega
        into GrupoB

Lo anterior en su momento lo hice a cada objeto del context que está después del in del alias.
ACTUALIZACIÓN 04 de Julio de 2024
Será revisar si el error por NULL se genera en el select new TemGeneMttoPrevObras... o en lo previo; te sugiero deshabilites está inicialización/asignación y el
return q.OrderBy(a => a.Obra).ThenBy(a => a.Estado).ToList();

lo deshabilites (de manera temporal) y agregues (temporalmente):
return List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras>();

Para devolver un List vacío y no interrumpir tu flujo ni generar un error de compilación... El caso es que inicie y finalice; si esto ocurre, implica que en tu clase TemGeneMttoPrevObras debes establecer sea permitido valor null (la labor es identificar la propiedad/propiedades donde realizar los cambios).
Si de todas formas ocurre el error; es indicador los new {Equipo = a.equipo, Fecha = a.fecha_mantenimiento } (así y similares) para los objetos anónimos hay datos que así se están recibiendo y no lo permite.
Para éste escenario sería probar (no sé si lo acepte) indicar una conversión explícita con dato para permitir el null; para asignar valor null a propiedades de objetos anónimos (está en inglés); o dar un valor predeterminado a los null ejemplo:
new {Equipo = (int?)a.equipo, Fecha = (DateTime?) a.fecha_mantenimiento }

de lo contrario, entonces tendrías que optar por la opción 2 que previamente he planteado.

RobertoLeOr muchas gracias por ls respuesta. Lo que hice primero fue quitar TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros para que los objetos no fueran instanciados sino anónimos. Ahora me sale un error de datos null que no son permitidos. Con este error ahora debo hacer nuevamente un debug para identificar el campo problema. Si es posible, agradecemos nos expliques porque es mejor utilizar objetos anónimos y no instanciados, ya que tenía entendido que aunque instanciar va a demandar mas tiempo, garantizará que se comparen objetos iguales.

@GermanDavid La comparación de 2 objetos es por referencia sin son creados a partir de una clase y por valor sin creados a partir de un struct o record. No obstante nada de eso importa, porque la comparación del join la realiza SQL no C#. Todo ese linq que tienes se convierte a una query SQL
